# Matlab R2016a on Ubuntu 14.04 and JDK 1.7; Needed? Alternatives?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, matlab, jdk, openjdk

I have already successfully installed Matlab 2016a on Ubuntu 14.04. As the installer finished wrapping up, it notified me that I was missing some necessary compilers. I noticed that I had forgotten to install GCC, and took care of that without an issue, and Matlab 2016a launches [via terminal `matlab`] without an issue (weird scrolling bug though; `MEvent. CASE!` output in Command Window when two finger scrolling on a Lenovo Trackpad, in case its relevant). But the online documentation also mentions needing JDK 1.7 as well.

Digging around online, it seems that JDK 1.7 is no longer publicly available, and that Mathworks does not recommend using a different version of the JDK than is recommended for your specific release of Matlab.

So I guess I have two questions:

1. Do I even need the JDK for Matlab 2016a?
2. How critical is the recommendation of 'no mix-and-match' for JDK versions? Are there alternatives to JDK 1.7 that can be dropped right in place, without really being able to tell the difference? Could something like OpenJDK work (with minimal headaches)?

> Installed Toolboxes
>
> - Simulink
> - Control System
> - DSP System
> - Image Processing
> - Instrument Control
> - Optimization
> - Parallel Computing
> - Robotics System
> - Signal Processing
> - Simscape
> - Simscape Multibody
> - Simulink Control Design
> - Stateflow
> - Statistics and Machine Learning
> - Symbolic Math

Comment: There are several possible solutions in the answers to [Installing Java 7 on Ubuntu](//stackoverflow.com/q/16263556)

Comment: That looks like it's for OpenJDK. This will be helpful if someone else can confirm that OpenJDK will work in place of Oracle's official version.